# A theorem about linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

English isn't my native language and maybe I didn't understand the theorem. Is it asking just to remove $x_{\beta}$ from the list? I didn't make it. How is it possible to remove a vector from a basis and still have a basis?

[image]

It's the exercise 10 from Greub's book Linear Algebra.

Comment: Probably there is a typo : the conclusion must be "show that the vectors $\lbrace x_{\alpha} \rbrace_{\alpha \neq \beta} \cup \lbrace a \rbrace$ form a basis of $E$".

Comment: @spohreis, after reading TheSilverDoe's comment, do you still need help with this? I can add that $\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha\neq\beta}$ is not a basis for $E$. You can try proving that as well. :)

Comment: @Aldoggen. No. The author did want to exchange $x_{\beta}$ for $a$. Thanks!

Comment: @spohreis, I agree with you and TheSilverDoe on that. My previous comment was confusing, sorry.

Do you still need help?

Comment: @Aldoggen. It's fine. Thanks!